# Meteor new Date() invalid with mongodb 3.0.1 and autoform/simple schema

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor, meteor-autoform

I've trouble dealing with a `type: Date` into SimpleSchema having a defaultValue.
In mongodb (3.0.1), the date entry have the time the meteor thread have been launch. The expected behaviour is to have "date" the insertion date of the object on the server.

lib/schema.js

```
Schema.DateCol = new SimpleSchema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    defaultValue: new Date()
  },
  dateModified: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function () { return new Date(); }
  }
});
```

client/home.html

```
    {{> quickForm id="test" schema="Schema.DateCol" collection="DateCol" type="insert" }}
```

Into the mongo, after inserting two objects:

- meteor thread launch at "Wed May 20 2015 12:28:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
- both objects have been inserted at one minute of interval: the first at 
  "Wed May 20 2015 12:30:50 GMT+0200 (CEST)" and the second at "Wed May 20 2015 12:31:30 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
- the date field (defaultValue) for both object is: "Wed May 20 2015 12:28:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

Object 1

```
{
  "_id": "PuME9jWwJJiw9diSC",
  "date": new Date(1432117722634),
  "dateModified": new Date(1432117850366)
}
```

Object 2:

```
{
  "_id": "qqHqkN4YapWDsFhxx",
  "date": new Date(1432117722634),
  "dateModified": new Date(1432117890380)
}
```

You'll fin enclose a repository Github with the error, using MongoDB 3.0.1 (I haven't this error on MongoDB 2.4): 
https://github.com/JVercout/meteor-defaultValue-date-errored

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `new Date()` expression is evaluated once when the code creating the schema is run. That value is then used as the `defaultValue`. There is no difference between:

```js
var x = new SimpleSchema({
  date: {defaultValue: new Date(), ...}
});
```

and

```js
var defaultDate = new Date();
var x = new SimpleSchema({
  date: {defaultValue: defaultDate, ...}
});
```

It looks like you'll need an `autoValue`, since it doesn't look like you can use a function for `defaultValue`. The [Collection2 documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#autovalue) actually has an example of using `autoValue` for a "created at" field. It depends on fields added by Collection2 but I saw in your git repo that you're using that.

```js
// Force value to be current date (on server) upon insert
// and prevent updates thereafter.
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  autoValue: function() {
    if (this.isInsert) {
      return new Date();
    } else if (this.isUpsert) {
      return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
    } else {
      this.unset();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All `new Date` should be `new Date()`, yes?

Comment: `new Date` does the same thing as `new Date()` but `new Date()` might be better style, I'll update them